# How can I use "include.yaml" in google appengine to share a library within two apps?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, include, yaml

I have two different applications on GAE, but both have some code in common.

I wanted to share that code but I can't find a way to import a .py file that's not in the same directory as the main app.

I think that "includes" in the yaml file could be what I need (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Includes) but I can't find any example on how to use it.

I understand I need an include.yaml file, but what should I write in it!?

Is there some more documentation I'm missing?

I can't find a way to import that code in my main app... is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not necessary.

Make sure you include the path to the file with `sys.setpath()` pointing to the directory containing the other python code, and put an `__init__.py` in that directory.

The best place to do this is in `appengine_config.py`